# Sending file in post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In python I send files like this:

```
with open('D:\\someimage.jpg', 'rb') as image:
imager = image.read()
files = {'image': imager}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I want to do similar thing in js, but I always get 400 Bad Request error. The problem, I assume, is that I don't know what type the file should have. I've tried passing it in initial 'file' type, as array buffer, as binary string - nothing works. Here is my code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(aFiles[0]);
reader.onload = function () {
var arrayBuffer = this.result,
array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/streamer', 
    method: 'POST',
    files: {'image': binaryString},
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send the file as a FormData (multipart/form-data) if you need to send more fields or as a Blob if you just want to send the binary directly.

jQuery tries to be smart about processing the data you send. But jQuery don't understand FormData or blobs, it sees it as an object and do the wrong thing. that's why you need to set `processData = false` and don't set the wrong request content-type by doing `contentType = false` and just let the xhr do that itself.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image', aFiles[0] /*, optional filename */)

var req = jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/streamer', 
  method: 'POST',
  data: fd, // sends fields with filename mimetype etc
  // data: aFiles[0], // optional just sends the binary
  processData: false, // don't let jquery process the data
  contentType: false // let xhr set the content type
});

// jQuery is promise A++ compatible and is the todays norms of doing things 
req.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
}, function(xhr) {
  console.error('failed to fetch xhr', xhr)
})
```

But you don't really need jQuery for this things if you only support the latest browser that has the [fetch api](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch)

```
var req = fetch('/streamer', {
  method: 'post',
  body: fd /* or aFile[0]*/
}); // returns a promise

req.then(function(response) {
  // returns status + response headers
  // but not yet the body, 
  // for that call `response[text() || json() || arrayBuffer()]` <-- also promise

  if (res.ok) {
    // status code was 200-299
  } else {
    // status was something else
  }
}, function(error) {
  console.error('failed due to network error or cross domain')
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm still getting 400 error... This is how the request looks like in Postman: [link](http://i65.tinypic.com/25gatq8.jpg)

Comment: oh, i forget `method: post` in the fetch example. that might have been it, just edited

Comment: I tried using ajax call from your first example. Can't figure out what's wrong with it

Comment: hmm, try looking at the request header in you developer tool and try to see the difference

Comment: with the fetch example I get "status was something else"

Comment: the response content-type can be text/plain but the request content-type should be multipart/form-data what dose the response text say?

Comment: the response is 400 Bad Request

Comment: request payload [object Object]... is that ok?

Comment: ok, well, if formdata didn't work are u using a old IE version then?

Comment: Suprisingly, I was using Opera 54.0