# How to send both text and binary data in axios post request?

Tags: javascript, java, post, axios

I would need to find a solution to send via a single axios POST request both of the following:

1. json structure
2. binary file (excel file)

How can I achieve this?

```
  let files = event.target.files;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsText(files[0], null);
  fileReader.onload = () => {
    this.fileContent = fileReader.result;

  let binaryDataForObject = this.fileContent;

  let referenceDataStructure = {
    textData: textDataForObject,
    binaryData: binaryDataForObject,
    referenceDataFileExtension: this.referenceDataFileExtension,
    userProvidedDataTypes: this.columnTypes
  };
  }

  this.axios
    .post(
      "http://url,
      referenceDataStructure
  )
```

This works technically but on the java side I couldn't figure out, how to decode the binary data (encoded as a string) so that it is treated as an excel file.

Thank You in advance for any meaningful responses.
Lubos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. With simple `POST` request you can send only up to 1mb of binary data
2. To send binary and text in one request you should use `FormData`

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706995/12038615) for information

### Update 14.12

How I managed to do this in my recent project was using `FormData`

So firstly you need to get file as a blob:

```js
const fileReader = new FileReader()
// Here we will get the file as binary data
fileReader.onload = () => {
  const MB = 1000000;
  const Blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {
                   // This will set the mimetype of the file
                   type: fileInputRef.current.files[0].type
                 });
  const BlobName = fileInputRef.current.files[0].name;
  if (Blob.size > MB) return new Error('File size is to big');

  // Initializing form data and passing the file as a param
  const formData = new FormData();
  // file - field name, this will help you to read file on backend
  // Blob - main data to send
  // BlobName - name of the file, default it will be name of your input
  formData.append('file', Blob, BlobName);

  // Append json data
  formData.apped('some-key', someValue)

  // then just send it as a body with post request
  fetch('/api/submit-some-form-with-file', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
  // Handle the rest
  .then()
}

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInputRef.current.files[0])
```

You can wrap this example in handle submit function in react and like or use it as is

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank You! This helped me a lot in finding a solution for my problem.